# Temp file trying to save to non-existing location

Tags: excel, vba

I am having issues with the below module. Well, my colleagues are and I don't know how to resolve. When I run the sub myself, it works fine, but some of my colleagues are getting an error. It looks as though it's trying to save the temp file to a folder that doesn't exist.

Is there a way I can amend the code to save the temp file to a specific location?

Thank you.

```
Sub Email_Sheet()

Dim oApp As Object
Dim oMail As Object
Dim LWorkbook As Workbook
Dim LFileName As String

ActiveSheet.Calculate
SubjectPanel = InputBox("Please Enter the Time") & " text"

'Turn off screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Copy the active worksheet and save to a temporary workbook
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set LWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

'Create a temporary file
LFileName = LWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
On Error Resume Next
'Delete the file if it already exists
Kill LFileName
On Error GoTo 0
'Save temporary file
LWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=LFileName

'Create an Outlook object and new mail message
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)


With oMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    .To = "" & _
    "address"
    .CC = "" & _
    "other address"
    .Subject = SubjectPanel
    .Body = "Hello all," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "body" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Thank you."
    .Attachments.Add LWorkbook.FullName
  .Display
End With

'Delete the temporary file and close temporary Workbook
LWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
Kill LWorkbook.FullName
LWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

'Turn back on screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your line

```
LWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=LFileName
```

put this line:

```
Debug.Print LWorkbook.FullName
```

Now when your colleague runs it, ask them to open the VBA editor first, and ask them to make sure the Immediate window is shown. Then get them to run it, and ask them what is shown in the Immediate window after the error. (It would be also useful if you say what the actual error was, and where in the code it stops at, but I'll make some assumptions about that!).

When I run your code with my extra line, on a new workbook, my Immediate window shows `C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Sheet1.xlsx`. And it then saves the temporary file with that name and folder.

If you can ask your colleague what theirs says, then you can find out if that folder perhaps does not allow write permission (ask them to try to save something into that folder).

If this is the problem (if I have assumed correctly!), then you need to change your `SaveAs` line to add the path where they do have permission. For example:

```
LWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\" & LFileName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a path to the save location for the temporary file.

```
'Save temporary file
LWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\" & LFileName
```

Comment: I just stuck in c:\temp\ as a path example. But yes, 'Environ("Temp")' would get that for you.  Wouldn't it actually get the users\temp directory?

Comment: Well, it depends on the environment, but yes it will be something like `C:\Users\stuartd\AppData\Local\Temp`